# How can I find out where I put this snippet of code?

Tags: debian

A while back, I was setting up a SFTP account for a developer and I used: [Internal SFTP Settings](https://serverfault.com/questions/198312/internal-sftp-settings)

I don't know which file I put that in. How can I find it? Is there a way to search all my files in my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put it in /etc/ssh/sshd_config (at least on CentOs, Debian and Ubuntu)
Then restart the SSH server through /etc/init.d/sshd restart